# Show $\sqrt{2}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n kX_k \to N(0,1)$ in distribution where $P(X_k=\pm 1)=1/2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Let $X_k$ be independent identically distrbuted random variables such that 
$$ P(X_k=1)=P(X_k=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$$
for all $k\geq 1$. Prove that
$$ \sqrt{\frac{2}{n^3}}\sum_{k=1}^n kX_k$$
converges to $N(0,1)$ in distribution.

Here's what I got so far:

The characteristic function for the $X_k$ is 
$$\phi_{X_k}(t) = \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2} = \cos(t).$$
So, the characteristic function of $Y_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n kX_k$ is 
$$\phi_{Y_n}(t) = \cos(t)\cos(2t)\cdots \cos(nt).$$

So it boils down to showing that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_{ \sqrt{\frac{2}{n^3}}\sum_{k=1}^n kX_k}(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n \cos\left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{n^3}}kt\right) $$
is the characteristic function of $N(0,1)$ which is $e^{-t^2/2}$. Is the product known to be that? Or is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Have a look to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2082519/144421).

Comment: That answer is a bit intense. I can barely follow it. I'm wondering if there is an easy way.

Comment: I dont´t think so.

Comment: An idea could be to look at the logarithm of the product, which consists of positive terms, at least for $n$ large enough. Then use a Taylor expansion.